# Fail to insert the element of the set to the vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, insert

Given a set of integers:

```
set<int> setA = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Now I want to insert the integer to a vector of integers under a certain condition:

```
vector<int> vectorB;
for (set<int>::iterator it = setA.begin(); it != setB.end(); it++){

  if (*it % 2 == 0){
  }else{
    vectorB.insert((*it));
    count += 1;
  }
}
```

But I got an error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<int>::insert(const int&)'
```

Why?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert - There isn't really any "official" C++ documentation, but cppreference is very good.

Comment: To simply add (without other requirements) element to the collection, you should use `push_back` and not `insert`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Actually I did. But I can not find the answer immediately. Now I got it. Thanks.

Comment: If you can't find the answer "immediately", spend a few more minutes reading. Not everything can be solved "immediately". Some patience required.

Comment: @yobichi Surly it took longer to write this question than to read the [description](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) of `std::vector::insert`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit got it.

Comment: @Daniel sorry, my false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have mentioned in the comments, you should not be using [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) in this case, you should be using [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)

```
vectorB.push_back(*it);
```

You would typically use `insert` if there is a *specific position* that you want to insert the new element. If you are not interested in adding the element to a specific position, then you can use `push_back` to (as the name suggests) add the element to the end of the vector.